how to find duplicate results in elasticsearch 6
I had an elasticsearch with version 6, now I need to find duplicate documents in a index "es_index" by field "userName" with same field value. That means I need to write query like sql:
  select userName, count(*) from es_index group by userName having count(*) > 1

How do I write DSL for es?
add:
Similar question "How to find all duplicate documents in ElasticSearch", can Not solve my problem. Result is after chinese word segment(tokenization). For example, I have 3 docs with field 'userName' as '上海某公司', '北京另一公司', '上海某公司'(duplicated), but the result is like:
{
    "aggregations": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "公",
                "doc_count": 3
            },{
                "key": "司",
                "doc_count": 3
            },{
                "key": "上",
                "doc_count": 2
            },{
                "key": "海",
                "doc_count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}

Instead, I want aggs with NO word segmentation, might be below:
"key": "上海某公司",
"doc_count": 2

I searched a lot, tried a lot, but still get no answer.

This question is similar to: How to find all duplicate documents in ElasticSearch. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you @GBlodgett, but it doesn't work. I got results after word segmentation.

I had solved this problem. The field 'userName' type is text, so word segmetation will be used on it. So I add a new field and aggs at the new field.
First, I add a new field 'userNameKw' with type keyword.
PUT /index/_mapping/type
{
  "properties": {
    "userNameKw": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}

Second, assign value of 'userName' to new field 'userNameKw'.
POST /index/type/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.userNameKw = ctx._source.userName;",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}

At last, aggregation at new field just as 'How to find all duplicate documents in ElasticSearch' does.
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "userNameAgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userNameKw",
        "min_doc_count":2
      }
    }
  }
}

